# Efficient implementation of this simple relation in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, data-modeling

1. User has an email address and a display name.
2. Both of these must be unique.
3. Both of these must be updatable as long as either is not being used already.
4. A User  table will exist with additional non-key attributes and a guid ID.

How to model to support efficient query check if email address or display name is already being used?

Should I create a table with the guid as Key, no range, and 2 separate GSI one for email and one for display name (each being the key)? Both will also have a second field with the guid id of the user. Or should these be completely separate tables, or ????

Thoughts, is there a better way?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways you can design that I can think of:

1. As you have mentioned, a table with guid and 2 separate GSI one for email and other for Name.
2. You have stated that both the fields had to be unique, so potentially you can make any one of them as hash and create GSI for other.(This will run into problem as you mention that you need to update Email & Name as well, for that you have to delete old record and add a new record with same attributes and updated Hash keys)

   Advantage of this would be that you need to pay less as there will be only one GSI compared to #1.
3. Another option is to use CloudSearch, your DynamoDB table can be integrated with cloudSearch, in this option you can simply create a table with guid no need to add any GSI, whenever you want to search you can search on CloudSearch to get the output.

   One more advantage you will get in CloudSearch is that you will be able to query on any attributes of the table and can use different filters on them.

   One thing you need to see it that price difference between #2 and #3, you can go with anyone which is better suited in terms of price and functionality.

If you implement this with other ways feel free to share it.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you.  Regarding option 3, I  like it, but I have   been  told a few months ago via aws  support that  clouddsearch will be discontinued  in the future in favor of hosted  Elastic Search.